# How to get android device activites without using “Google fit”

Tags: android

Is there any way to get activities done by user from Android device like active time, inactive time, cyclic distance, steps count etc. without using “Google fit” api like M9 chip does in iPhone devices.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i found to get device activity by help of **"Google APIs for Android"** .Here you cannot get the proper count but can get the device activation mode.Please see below link

[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity]